# On Carmichael function and aliquot parts of odd perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, carmichael-function

This post is cross-posted on MathOverflow with identifier [**439563**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439563/on-carmichael-function-and-aliquot-parts-of-odd-perfect-numbers) and same title.

We denote as $N$ an odd perfect number, and $d\mid N$ one of its divisors. We denote the Carmichael function as $\lambda(x)$, Wikipedia has the article [*Carmichael function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) dedicated to this number theoretic function.

> **Question.** I would like to know if on assumption that $N$ is an odd perfect number we can to prove or refute that there exists a divisor $d\mid N$ with
> $$1<d<N\tag{1}$$
> such that $$\lambda\left(\frac{N}{d}\right)\mid \sigma\left(\frac{N}{d}\right)\tag{2}$$
> holds, where $\sigma(x)$ denotes the sum of divisor function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid x}d$. **Many thanks.**

I've known the definition of Carmichael function from page 21 of the book [1] and the propositions and examples showed in pages 144-146 (below CMS means Canadian Mathematical Society). I think that this question isn't in the literature. I don't know if it is possible to deduce some proposition about my question.

### References:

[1] Michal Krizek, Florian Luca, and Lawrence Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat Numbers*, CMS Books in Mathematics, Springer (2001).

Comment: Interesting question (+1) although probably pointless because the existence of an odd perfect number is very unlikely.

Comment: Many thanks @Peter

Comment: I've asked the question on MathOverflow with identifier **439563** and same title.